# Ajax POST call returns 404, even though script is there

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using an Ajax call like so

```
var sHTML = $('.is-wrapper').data('contentdiv').html();

$.ajax({

    type: "post",
    data: {
        html_data: sHTML
    },
    url: "path_to_file.html",
    success: function (data) {
        alert("Data Save: " + data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

When calling this, the script says my "path_to_file.html" is returning a 404 error, however, the file is there because when I click on the file link in the console, the file exists. Any idea what could be causing this?

(Error thrown just says "error")

Comment: Check the request in the Network panel in Developer Tools.

Comment: where you are hosting the application?IIS? or running as localhost?

Comment: It's on a LAMP server

Comment: The request says 404 page not found, but the page is definitely there

Comment: Hey guys, I believe the issue is the variable sHTML contains long string of html code, is there a way to remedy this?

Comment: Check the 404 in the Apache logs. Maybe the url was not what you think it was. After all you specified a relative url, not one starting with /

Comment: Also maybe it's because you use type/method `post` instead of `POST`, and Apache rejects the unknown HTTP verb or ajax defaults to GET because of that misspelling and overflows the query string?

Comment: I've updated it to method POST and it still does not work. Also I realized that when I shortened the sHTML variable it worked. So that means sHTML variable is the cause of it, maybe its too long or because the variable contains code.

Answer (score 0):

OP here and found out the issue. Server was having "modsec" error. Get your server admin to fix.